# Changing the properties of a JButton through references

Tags: java, swing, variables, reference, jbutton

I'm trying to a make a reference to the last button that is clicked. When this button is clicked i want to store it and then be able to manipulated it. So then what ever the user clicks I can go back and change it. Is it possible to change the properties of a Jbutton through the use of references?

### Something like;

```
JButton original = new JButton(" This is text");
JButton lastbuttonclicked;

lastbuttonclicked = original;

lastbuttonclicked.setText("This new text is this"); 

System.out.println(original.getText());
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

### "The new text is this"

I feel like the issue is that I am just creating a new JButton, but i never substantiate the new object.

How would I change a button using references?

Comment: Try creating a method that takes a parameter of a `JButton` and do it that way.

Comment: A runnable example would go a long way to reducing the amount of guess work

Comment: I don't quite understand your question as your example generates the desired output by modifying ```lastbuttonclicked``` which is a reference to ```original```. Are you asking more on how to save the last clicked button and recall it at a given moment afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Warning: pseudocode.

```
private Button[] lastButton = new Button[1];

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // the button that has been clicked
    lastButton[0] = (Button) e.getSource();
}
```

Then just `lastButton[0]` whenever you want to access it. The array should store the reference and not an object, as best I know (for complete assurance, use an ArrayList).